# Android 5(HTC) EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-permissions, android-file

app can't create `folder/file` on `android 5(HTC HTC6525LVW os version: 5.0.1)` external storage in directory owned by app.

Parent folder is returned by `[getExternalFilesDirs(String type)][1]` method.

`Sdcard` is mounted.

Anyone else having this problem or suggestion how to solve it?

***(Unfortunately I don't have this device to test it more)***

Edit: From one user I know that prior this bug she encrypted sdcard and then formatted it.

Comment: You should try this again with a phone that's not the HTC with the **exact** same configuration (same USB debugging mode, same installation process, etc.) and see if it's just an android thing or if it's an HTC thing.

Comment: Are you trying to create folder/file from a class from the same package as the class that called `getExternalFilesDirs(String)`?

Comment: @helleye yes, same package

Comment: Have you tried to run on another device with v5.0.1? In general, on which devices and Android versions have you successfully(and not) run your app?

Comment: @helleye problem is only on device specified in my question.

Answer (score 9):

Some potential ideas as to what caused it:

1. If the phone is running in USB Storage mode when connected to your computer you can still deploy/debug like normal but write operations will fail
2. You were missing a permission: in your manifest file you should check to see if you have  `<permission name=”android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” >`
3. Permissions in the wrong location: make sure that your permission tag (in manifest) is located *outside* of the application
4. Writing to the `data` folder can cause issues like this so make sure you're writing to `sdcard` and not `data`

This is everything I could think of. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for answer but none of these points is true in this case.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. Not that much to go on :/

Answer (score 0):

Add permission to your manifest.xml file permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: I have both permission already even when for getExternalFilesDirs, no permission is required.

Comment: Since Android KitKat, calling getExternalFilesDirs() method does not require any permissions.